# Incluir números para completar sequência númerica em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Neste caso tenho o resultado no MYSQL.

```
01
03
06
09
```

Preciso completar com o número **correto da sequência** até o algarismo 12.

Exemplo:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse é para "incluir" os números. Mas sim, poderia já ser tratado direto no loop. rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vejo bem a necessidade completar, seguindo a necessidade atual que soa, parece que apenas precisa de 1 a 12, sendo assim o uso de `range` com `str_pad` já resolveria:

```
$valores = range(1, 12);

$valores = array_map(function ($item) {
    return str_pad($item, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, $valores);

var_dump($valores);
```

Algo que penso que talvez faria sentido seria você pesquisar os numeros que faltam e retorna-los:

```
function array_missing(array $arr, $min = 12)
{
    $max = max($arr);

    //Se no array tiver um valor maior que o $min
    if ($max > $min) {
       $min = $max;
    }

    $values = range(1, $min);

    $values = array_map(function ($item) {
        return str_pad($item, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, $values);

    return array_diff($values, $arr); 
}

$exemplo = array( '01', '03', '06', '09');

var_dump(array_missing($exemplo));
```

> Nota: o `$min = 12` é para definir o minimo a ser gerado, se o array tiver um valor maior então vai gerar mais itens.

Desta maneira irá retorna **os que faltam**:

> ```
> array(8) {
>   [1]=>
>   string(2) "02"
>   [3]=>
>   string(2) "04"
>   [4]=>
>   string(2) "05"
>   [6]=>
>   string(2) "07"
>   [7]=>
>   string(2) "08"
>   [9]=>
>   string(2) "10"
>   [10]=>
>   string(2) "11"
>   [11]=>
>   string(2) "12"
> }
> ```

Pode depois simplesmente fazer mesclar ambos, por exemplo:

```
$exemplo = array( '01', '03', '06', '09');

$faltam = array_missing($exemplo);

$final = array_merge($exemplo, $faltam);

sort($final); //Ordena a array

var_dump($final);
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo range do proprio PHP faz isso de maneira bem simples.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade para resolver isso é:

```
<?php 
$array_do_banco = array('01', '03', '04', '06', '11');
$array_saida = array();

for($i=1; $i<13; $i++){
    if(in_array($i, $array_do_banco)){
        $matches = array_keys($array_do_banco, $i);
        $array_saida[$i-1] = $array_do_banco[$matches[0]];
    }else{
        $array_saida[$i-1] = str_pad($i , 2 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}

var_dump($array_saida);
?>
```

A saída é:

> array(12) { [0]=> string(2) "01" [1]=> string(2) "02" [2]=> string(2) "03" [3]=> string(2) "04" [4]=> string(2) "05" [5]=> string(2) "06" [6]=> string(2) "07" [7]=> string(2) "08" [8]=> string(2) "09" [9]=> string(2) "10" [10]=> string(2) "11" [11]=> string(2) "12" }

Comment: A saída é https://ideone.com/sgGujr

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Interessante esse ideone. É que eu faço no localhost, então nunca tinha usado ele hehe.

Comment: Gosto mais desse que pode fazer modificação no código e clicar em `Execute code` sem ter que carregar a página a cada mudança. Veja http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ee559c13e7cd3410b085b0738513a97d14a34b6

Comment: Para testar pequenos pedaços de código é bem interessante mesmo. Muito obrigado :)